# How to use symfony packages from ubuntu repository

Tags: php, symfony

I realize that there are a lots of packages of Symfony 3.4 in ubuntu repositories but I can't find any docs of how to use those packages in any other project.

```
apt search php-symfony*
```

Does anyone know hot to use those packages.

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to know more about a package of ubuntu, download it, untar and inspect it: https://packages.ubuntu.com/

Comment: Composer packages are unrelated to ubuntu packages.  You can search on https://packagist.org/ to see what Symfony related packages are available.  And then look to the individual sites for details on what they do and how to use them.  If you are asking about individual Symfony libraries then the [Symfony component documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html#gsc.tab=0) is a good place to start.

Comment: @Cerad for some odd reason, Ubuntu do have Symfony packages, as the OP is asking: https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/php-symfony. Utterly outdated, though, because the recent Ubuntu 18.10 ships with Symfony Framework Bundle 3.4.15, if I read that properly...

Comment: Symfony 3.4 it's LTS version, so It makes sense to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No one of them. Use Composer and use the documentation to install your application. You can install it from the CLI or install it from composer directly.

https://symfony.com/download

```
symfony new my_project
```

Comment: Yes I know, I'm always use the way that Symfony propose, but I don't know what for are those packages...
Thanks any way...

Comment: In some cases programs use symfony as dependency and they are using the packages in the repo. I don't know an application at the moment but sometimes it's possible and then that dependencies are installed over the package manager.

Comment: I would like to know, sometimes I've deployed software in a VPN which has access to a private repo but not to internet and those packages are an option to satisfy dependencies... That's why I want to know...

Comment: There is some software to host a private repo for composer on your own. Satis was one of them. Or you could use Nexus then you need only one machine you can cache your repos and need some external access.

Comment: Well I'm pretty sure that those packages aren't useless but I don't find out any utility.
Thanks for your time